# Codeigniter: passing a value from jquery to the controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have decided to split my questions into parts to make it much more easier to understand:

The first issue is:

I have interdependent select lists, so I am going to be working with jquery

I have this snippet which gets me the id of the selected option:

```
    //jquery code for source list
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#f_state').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val()!='') {
        $("#f_city").load("./controller/control_form.php",{pais_id: $(this).val()});
      }
    // or should I use something like this instead..

var post_url = "./controllers/control_form/" + $(this).val();

but still dont know how to fetch at the controller
        });

    });
```

but..how do I actually send it to the controller ? Or from other point of view ? how do I retrieve it from the controller ? I have done it out of CI scenario, but in codeigniter ..don't know.

The thing is that if I manage to grab it at the controller, I can pass that index to the Model. The model would do the sql query and would yield an array back to the controller and from there I would print it back to the view to populate that second dropdown list.

thank you

regards

A

Answer (score 0):

In your `.load()` you are already passing in a data variable to the function, which is the data to be passed to the server. [Reading the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Since you are passing an object, all that is needed is to grab the POST data from inside Codeigniter. You can read up on this on their [documentation on the Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) in the section title **Using POST, COOKIE, or SERVER Data**. But basically you can now

```
$pais_id = $this->input->post('pais_id', TRUE);
```

Comment: Also note, you can use `$this->input->get_post('some_data', TRUE);` to have it search both POST and GET streams for data.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through that again. I already studied it on my first pass but I was not relating it to jquery.

Comment: Nope. It does not work. 100% sure. I have even tried to var_dump the variable and it reads: false boolean. This, according to the documentation means the value is not set, it is like the If isset, well, it is saying, it is not set, so, no value 'pais_id' has been passed from the jquery.

Comment: Everything is standard documented methods. Something else a-miss. I've looked at everything and all functions work as stated. Try using a program Web Inspector or something to view the network request from the browser to ensure it's sending the POST and the data. Also you can use `$_POST` in PHP to access the raw PHP variables ( http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php )